# MS Access adds always current day in time defined postgres column

Tags: postgresql, datetime, ms-access, odbc

We are moving BackEnd tables from a large MS Access application to postgresql.

In one table we have a field `ErZei` defined in postgres as

`time(0)` without time zone DEFAULT `('now'::text)::time(0)` without time zone

Inside this field only the time value is stored, the day value has his own field.

The linked table inside Access shows the current day in front of the time value. Using the 24-hour format for displaying time values in Access looks fine. But by entering the field, the current day appears automatically.
If I call the time field by SQL-Query `SELECT * from ...`, I get the same result: everytime the current day value in front of the time value.
Inside postgres everything works fine.
Also a test with a ODBC query tool shows only the time.

How could I configure MS Access to show only the time value without the day in case of postgres time columns?
I can't find an option in the Access globals.

We use

- MS Access 2016
- ODBC: PostgreSQL Unicode 10.00.00 PSQLODBC35W.DLL
  13.10.2017
- PostgreSQL 10.1 as backend on ubuntu

Comment: have you tried field.format property to shortTime/longtime?

Comment: thanks for helping
I have already tried this. Displaying the time value as short time runs good. But the problem is editing the time value.
After focus the input control the edit masks add the current day whatever I defined as input mask.